# SSL Certificate disappears on refresh Windows server

Tags: windows, ssl, ssl-certificate, pem

I bought a wildcard SSL certificate and I need to install it on a Windows server, by the way on the IIS in the server certificate page after I've imported the certificate and completed the certificate request the certificate disappear on refresh.

Doing research I've discovered that the pem files with the private keys were missing, now I have the keys but the certificate disappeared on refresh too.

How can I bind the certificate with the key?

What I'm missing?

I've read e followed all the official Windows guide and docs and nothing works.

Comment: I'm *assuming* you're talking about **IIS** (the Windows-Server based web server) - not the **ISS** (International Space Station) ....

Comment: Yes it is, my bad

Answer (score 1):

I've solved installing OpenSSL and running the following command to produce a pfx file.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt
```

Then I've installed the certificate by just importing the file on the certificate section in IIS.

The last step was binding the certificate on the server section on IIS.

With the pfx file just follow this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/install-imported-certificates#assign-the-imported-certificate-to-the-web-site